# exe C# installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation

I need:
Create .NET 2.0 application (let's call it application Checker.exe), .NET 4.0 application (let's call it application Inst.exe) and another .NET 4.0 application(let's call it application Program.exe).
**The Application Checker.exe** must check if .NET 4.0 Framework is installed in computer. 
**If not** - launch .NET 4.0 installation. After installation application Checker.exe must launch application Inst.exe and closes itself.
**If yes** application Checker.exe must launch application Inst.exe and closes itself.
The Application Inst.exe is installer. It installs .NET 4.0 application(Program.exe)

Maybe it's easy, but I really have no experience of working with installations. MSDN have too  much information. I don't know what to choose. Give me advice, please.

Comment: The MSDN only has too much information if you don't know how to use google and type the words c# installer tutorial here - try this : http://bit.ly/tytFKN

Comment: I am sure this can be done by only installation wizard (Inst.exe), take a look at [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx) perhaps there are some better alternatives

Answer (score 2):

You can create *Setup projects* in VS that have 'dependencies' (i.e - .NET FW installed).

You can google it,
[Here's](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html) an example.

Comment: I don't need a standard Visual Studio Setup Project. And the main task is how to launch Inst.exe by Checker.exe after .NET Framework 4.0 installing and close Checker.exe

Comment: What you want is provided by a Setup Project.  Much easier to use what is already there then create it yourself. You are not really suppose to distrubute the .NET Framework yourself.

Comment: Please, just give me the sample of code. Even not for my task. I want to see how to make non-a standard Visual Studio Setup Project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing installers, Read:

[Application Deployment Prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx)

[How to: Install Prerequisites in Windows Installer Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx)